# VNC viewer issue - showing black screen

Tags: linux

Vnc viewer is showing black screen. Following are the configuration : Please figure out the issue ?

```
cat /root/.vnc/xstartup

#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
 unset SESSION_MANAGER
 exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
twm &
====================================================================



vi /etc/sysconfig/vncservers

 VNCSERVERS="2:root"

 VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1024x768"
```

=================================================================

Run level :

```
chkconfig --list vncserver
vncserver       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Comment: Which distro is server running? Make sure that it is running at runlevel 5.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured I should answer my own question...in case anyone else runs into a similar problem. I just added localhost to xhost, and *voila*! took me a lot of hunting around to find this solution, so maybe this'll help a couple of you.

```
chmod 775 xstartup
```

Comment: Your solution helped. The question is why it's not executable by default???

Comment: For me it was a matter of just (re-)running `~/.vnc/xstartup`  *shrug*

Answer (score 2):

Same issue.  It seems that there is a dbus-launch in anaconda2/bin.  If a user has that in their path vncserver fails to find the correct dbus-launch - /usr/bin/dbus-launch.  The Xvnc starts but none of the window manager applications that depend on dbus.  My fix was to create a /usr/local/bin/vncserver:

```
#!/bin/bash
#added because there is a dbus command in /usr/local/anaconda2/bin !!!!
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
# added because nvidia driver overwrites these - tkovacs 5/23/19
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/vnclib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/bin/vncserver $*
```

Comment: Thanks!  This turned out the be the cause of the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same symptom. For me, the issue was how I used bsub to invoke vncserver.

Using 'bsub -Is' caused a black screen. Using 'bsub -I' fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was launching x0vncserver from a remote ssh terminal.  The server would run, but then connecting to vncviewer would show the black screen as mentioned above.

**The solution: 
Launching x0vncserver from a terminal window on the host gnome environment.**

I use this configuration with win2vnc, so I get dual monitor Windows + 3rd monitor linux side-by-side with one keyboard and mouse.  Works great!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case dbus-daemon (/usr/bin/dbus-daemon) was getting masked by another dbus daemon in my PATH.  I found this by checking the vncserver logs for my session.  In typical setup can be accessed in .vnc directory in user home area.  The start of specific log message may look like this:

```
Failed to execute message bus daemon
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems one user can only start one kde desktop, the extras are black screen. Just now xdm and vnc show me the desktop, I think, is because I don't login to the desktop.

Replace sddm to xdm fix the black screen problem, refert to this:
https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/532320-vncserver-blank-screen

```
Switch your Display Manager to XDM, KDM (you would have to install that in Yast, first), or LightDM on the machines you are trying to access.

Code:
su -
and give the password, then:
Code:
update-alternatives --config default-displaymanager
choose your Display Manager from the list.

SDDM does not work well with VNC yet.
```