# VNC black screen kills Vmware Workstation sessions on host

Tags: vmware-workstation, vnc

There are other similar questions related to mine (e.g. [VNC viewer issue - showing black screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/319056/vnc-viewer-issue-showing-black-screen) ) - my case seems a little bit different: 
I start vncserver on my CentOS 5.8 host, which acts as a VMware Workstation 8.0 host, and use TigerVNC to open a desktop window from my Fedora box.

I get the twm desktop as expected (have several similar setups), and start vmware (relevant here, I think).

All seems to work like a charm, i.e. I operate on the VMware WS GUI, able to start/stop, or enter/exit each VM console etc.

But if I leave it inactive for a while, the VNC window goes suddenly black... and the whole VMware environment that was running *is killed*... all the VM instances are gone ! *(vmrun list count is 0 !)*. A most undesirable situation - as I must then hurry to restart them via ssh.

Closing the TigerVNC client doesn't help - when opening it again, the black screen continues showing. Only killing vncserver (vncserver -kill :1) fixes this... until the next occurrence...

The vncserver configs are the default ones.. and as said other machines that I have are stable (can leave the VNC client desktop open for days at once).

Any hint ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that the VNC server crashes for some reason and brings VMWare down with it. Is there anything interesting in the logs in ~/.vnc on the server?

Comment: Sorry for the abandoned thread - nothing useful in the logs, however. I've been just careful not to repeat the inviting behavior - no unattended VNC sessions...

Comment: Try `xset s off` to turn off the screen saver function in a session. Will it still crash your VMware workstation? A workaround with VMWare server might be an option. Then killing the GUI won't kill the vm. (Unless you do not want to move to ESX altogether)